# How to get a div to line up to the right of another div instead of below it?

Tags: css, layout, html

```
<div id="holder">

    <div id="topleft">
    </div>

    <div id="topright">
    </div>

    <div id="main">
    </div>

</div>
```

I have these divs on my page and no matter what I do, `topright` goes underneath `topleft` instead of to the right of it, making a T shape of content on the page with the `topleft` and `topright` forming a header section above the `main` content below them.

What would cause it to keep dropping below `topright`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

divs are block elements so by default they are 100% of their container. So you have to float them and give them a width.

```
#topleft, #topright { float:left; width: 300px } // put in your own width
```

Comment: +1 , though I think a recommendation to @wiki of using classes over using IDs is in order.

Comment: @jball, why do you think he should use classes?

Comment: @Galen, classes are more portable. If they need to reuse this pattern in another part of the page or on a different page where the `div`s have different ids, using the id for styling breaks down, but classes handle those situations easily.

Comment: Well thats why you use IDs (which are faster for browsers to match) for certain situations and classes for others. in this situation it may be better for him to use IDs. It's impossible to tell without more knowledge of his situation.

Comment: @Galen IDs are definitely an option, I just would recommend against it, for reasons better explained by [people smarter than me](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/)

Answer (score 2):

in your css, add the following:

```
#topleft{
 float: left;
}


#main{
 clear: left;
}
```

The 'clear: left' will make sure that your main content displays below the two other DIV blocks.